# How to set the default quality of Screenshot in Firefox

Tags: firefox

We can take screenshot with a desired quality by a console command like `:screenshot --dpr 2 --fullpage` as described [here](https://jackharner.com/blog/high-dpi-firefox-screenshots), but how can we set the default quality of screenshot that's taken by right click menu? I hope it doesn't need any extension.

Comment: Did you try zooming in to say 400% by hitting CTRL + a bunch of times until you reach say 400%, then trying a regular screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure the term "quality" is appropriate here. The quality is always 100%—screenshots are either copied to clipboard or saved as PNG. Changing the device pixel ratio is entirely unrelated to quality IMHO.